# Is Pirkei Avos missing from Siddur Sfas Yisrael Shabbat Mincha and if so, Why?

Tags: shabbat, prayer-book, mincha-afternoon-prayer, pirke-avot-ethicsof

Is Pirkei Avos missing from Siddur Sfas Yisrael Shabbat Mincha  and if so, Why?

http://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Tefiloh-Sefas-Yisroel-8-Mincha-for-Shabbat-and-Yom-Tov.pdf

Comment: cause it just pdf siddur ?

Comment: the file format has nothing to do with it! And the siddur sfas yisroel is not some badly written siddur with huge mistakes in it! It's a classic siddur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Siddur is fine, but that PDF supposedly with just Shabbat Mincha, has cut it too soon.

Here is the whole siddur PDF

http://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Tefiloh-Sefas-Yisroel-Open-Siddur.pdf

And you see there Shabbat Mincha has Pirkei Avot and Barachi Nafshi

Comment: So it does have Pirkei Avot, what is your point?

Comment: @havarka do you mean what is my question? or what is my answer?

Comment: yes, in one pdf it appears, in another it doesn', nu, so what?

Comment: @havarka The question was that the siddur seemed to be missing it (as shown in the PDF the OP linked). The answer was that it is in the sidur itself, it was just the linked PDF that was cut short. Apparently the questioner found the fuller PDF after the question was posted.